# indexing ajax website - parallel pages still needed?

Tags: ajax, indexing, seo

I am building a single-page website that brings text html fragments. The fragments are in static html files stored at the server. Do I have to provide parallel pages for SEO indexing? I am hoping this technology improved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific, so we can help you better.

Escaped fragments is the recommended way to get Google to index your AJAX-site. [Read more about them here.](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

I don't know what you mean by parallel, but `?_escaped_fragment_=key=value` should result in a HTML snapshot of the page `#!key=value`